# How to give title to audio tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to give tooltip to audio tag in html

[image: audio Image]

Comment: What do you mean? What is title here?

Comment: @VuHuuCuong tooltip

Comment: @VuHuuCuong `title` is HTML attribute to add tooltips

Comment: Not in the places where you painted the red borders - not with just an audio element alone, because in that case these controls will be provided by the browser. You can suppress the default controls however and implement your own UI - then you have total freedom on what you put titles/tooltips etc. on.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `title` attribute.

```
<audio title="hello world" src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg" controls>
</audio>
```